# Transclude then replace with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I would like to create a directive that replaces :

```
   <my-overlay class="someOverlay">
      <h4>Coucouc</h4>
    </my-map-overlay>
```

With :

```
<div class="someOverlay default-overlay">
 <h4>Coucouc</h4>
</div>
```

The `replace` method is yet deprecated.

How to write a directive that manipules the DOM creating a `div`, adds the `default-overlay` class to the previous defined one, transcludes and replaces the `<my-map>` directive ?

Is it possible to divide the process as following : DOM manipulation in `compile` and transcluding in `link`?

Comment: Is it necessary for the `myOverlay` directive to be an element? Can you not restrict it to an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the commit for 'replace' to be removed:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb

If you read some of the last comments it seems that replace may not be deprecated after all. However this could be a way to achieve what uou want:

```
.directive('myOverlay', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.children()[0].setAttribute('class', element.attr('class') + ' default-overlay');
            element.replaceWith(element.children()[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b6ww0rx8/10/